# Accessing social media data's

Tags: bigdata, flume

I know that we can access data's from twitter and facebook using developers account.
But is it possible to access other social media contents? if yes How to access those data?
Provide me some social media sites that allows to access it's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Last.fm: http://www.last.fm/api

Youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Flickr: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Google Dev: https://developers.google.com/

Yahoo Dev: https://developer.yahoo.com/

Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/

Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/

http://mashable.com/2009/05/21/social-media-api/